Group After Pivoting without Numbers
I have a table where Fields are stored in one Column and their expected results are stored in another Column. The query is the following:
select EMPNO, ICODE, Type, Role from EMP_TBL

The query yields this result:



EMPNO
ICODE
Type
Training




579304
84338308
Intro
Welcome In Vid


579304
74287748
Intro
IT Support 2


579304
74728423
Compliance
Harassment Prev


283749
23873832
Compliance
Benefit Spclst


579304
46384742
Security
Phishing Email


526934
21222126
Security
Key Card Usage


183729
90384678
Project
Requesting Fund


283749
28653846
Project
Schedule Proces


686429
94748634
Role Based
Dashboard 101


283749
22733749
Role Based
Presentation



I then used the following query to pivot the fields:
select EMPNO, 
case when GROUP = 'Intro' then Role end as "Intro"
case when GROUP = 'Compliance' then Role end as "Compliance"
case when GROUP = 'Security' then Role end as "Security"
case when GROUP = 'Project' then Role end as "Project"
case when GROUP = 'Role Based' then Role end as "Role Based"
from EMP_TBL

The query yields this result:



EMPNO
Intro
Compliance
Security
Project
Role Based




579304
Welcome In Vid
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)


345678
IT Support 2
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)


579304
(null)
Harassment Prev
(null)
(null)
(null)


283749
(null)
Benefit Spclst
(null)
(null)
(null)


579304
(null)
(null)
Phishing Email
(null)
(null)


526934
(null)
(null)
Key Card Usage
(null)
(null)


183729
(null)
(null)
(null)
Requesting Fund
(null)


283749
(null)
(null)
(null)
Schedule Proces
(null)


686429
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
Dashboard 101


283749
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
Presentation



I am trying to generate a final result where a user with trainings in different types will have all their results in a single row. This would look like the following:



EMPNO
Intro
Compliance
Security
Project
Role Based




579304
Welcome In Vid
Harassment Prev
Phishing Email
(null)
(null)


345678
IT Support 2
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)


283749
(null)
Benefit Spclst
(null)
Schedule Proces
Presentation


526934
(null)
(null)
Key Card Usage
(null)
(null)


183729
(null)
(null)
(null)
Requesting Fund
(null)


686429
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
Dashboard 101



How can I achieve this without a group by as I cannot use group by without aggregating. This isn't possible as my fields aren't numerical values.
My dbms is Oracle SQL Developer

Where did you get EMPNO 345678?

You can certainly aggregate with min()/max() as there's only a single value in each column. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/

Which dbms are you using? Different products have different possibilities.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

This can be done with a pivot in Oracle.
SELECT  *
FROM  
(
  SELECT EMPNO,Type,Training
  FROM EMP_TBL
)   
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(Training)  
  FOR Type IN ('Intro', 'Compliance', 'Security', 'Project', 'Role Based')  
); 

Orcale fiddle
SQl-Server fiddle



EMPNO
Intro
Compliance
Security
Project
Role Based




183729
null
null
null
Requesting Fund
null


283749
null
Benefit Spclst
null
Schedule Proces
Presentation


526934
null
null
Key Card Usage
null
null


579304
Welcome In Vid
Harassment Prev
Phishing Email
null
null


686429
null
null
null
null
Dashboard 101




Another product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms... Same advice as last time, tell OP and the rest of the readers which dbms this is for.

I am trying to accomplish this in Oracle SQL Developer.

Im getting "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"  problem seems to be at the naming of the table.  I also replaced brackets with Quotes. @Bart McEndree

@JakeNotFromStatefarm Oracle example added https://dbfiddle.uk/j5WQOB62

Single quotes removed via aliasing https://dbfiddle.uk/A8SaVBHv
